# How to connect to a minikube cluster using terraform on jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, terraform, minikube

I need a kubernetes cluster for end to end tests. So I created a minikube cluster on the same machine on which jenkins is installed. jenkins installation is in the form of docker in docker which is on [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/).

I want to use terraform to provision a kubernetes cluster on minikube. Here is my main.tf:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://172.17.0.2:8443"

  client_certificate     = file("./client.crt")
  client_key             = file("./client.key")
  cluster_ca_certificate = file("./ca.crt")

  load_config_file = false

}

# Provisioning other resources here ...
```

`client.crt`, `client.key` and `ca.crt` are the files generated by minikube.

When I run terraform manually on my machine, everything works as expected. But when I run terraform using [jenkins terraform plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/terraform/) in my pipeline, It cannot connect to minikube.

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    tools { terraform 'terraform' }
    stages {
        stage('Terraform') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform init'
                sh 'terraform apply --auto-approve'
            }
        }
        stage('Selenium') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:3.7-alpine3.8-selenium' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'python selenium_test.py'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It cannot execute `terraform apply` because it cannot connect to minikube. Here is part of my pipeline output console:

```
+ terraform apply --auto-approve

[0m[1mkubernetes_deployment.helloworld: Refreshing state... [id=default/helloworld][0m

[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mGet "https://172.17.0.2:8443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/helloworld": dial tcp 172.17.0.2:8443: i/o timeout[0m

[0m[0m[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Selenium)
Stage "Selenium" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
```

And here is my start_jenkins.sh:

```
docker run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach \
  --privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --publish 2376:2376 docker:dind

docker build -t myjenkins-blueocean:1.1 .

docker run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach \
  --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  myjenkins-blueocean:1.1
```

I guess there is something wrong with `client.crt`, `client.key` and `ca.crt`. But I have done nothing to them. I just copied those files into my working directory (where `main.tf` exists).

What's the correct way to connect to a minikube cluster from jenkins pipeline?

***Edit***

I know it's a bad idea to place credentials like `client.crt`, `client.key` and `ca.crt` on code repository, But I just wanted to test.

Comment: Where and how are you starting minikube?  (Is it using a VM or a container, and if a container, which Docker daemon is it talking to?)

Comment: Thanks for your response! @DavidMaze. The minikube is on a VM and created using "minikube start"